# Django date form field can't accept |date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" filter

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

When looping over form fields for a ModelForm, I can apply the `date` filter to a `models.DateField()` just fine, i.e.

```
{{field.value|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT"}}
```

but when looping over a non-model form with a `forms.DateField`, the data seems to be in string format already, and returns an empty string when I apply the filter. When I `print type(form.cleaned_data['date'])` it comes out as datetime however. Is `is_valid()` modifying the form in anyway, or any ideas on how to apply the filter?

Comment: Do you want to print an initial value with specific format (SHORT_DATE_FORMAT), or want to re-format user's input if POST is invalid? And any reason that you must manually render the form instead of `{{form}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. the Json data i am getting back has the data as a string not a data object. so the date formatting template tag does not reconize it.

[the documentation says:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

If value is a datetime object (e.g., the result of datetime.datetime.now()), the output will be the string 'Wed 09 Jan 2008'.

so it looks like it we ether need to convert the string into a good looking date or convert the string into a datetime object so that the tag will convert it.

i will update with what seams the least painful.